# How to get Hadoop built-in Counters in GridGain In-Memoru Accelerator?

Tags: hadoop, gridgain

It is possible to get the Hadoop counters when running a mapreduce job with the GridGain accelerator? I can use custom counters that I've made, but it seems that the ones built-in Hadoop aren't there.

As an example of what I'm trying to do here's some of the code that I used for printing the counters:

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();

for (CounterGroup group : counters) {
        System.out.println("Group: " + group.getDisplayName() + "," + group.getName());
        System.out.println("  number of counters: " + group.size());
        for (Counter counter : group) {
            System.out.println("  - " + counter.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter.getName() + ": "+counter.getValue());
        }
}
```

Thanks for the attention!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GridGain Hadoop Accelerator the counters you get are empty because GG runs the jobs in its own map-reduce engine, not the Hadoop one, so built-in Hadoop counters and not available. Hadoop org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner has map-reduce progress counters, but in GG map-reduce engine the map-reduce job progress counters were not implemented.
You can submit a ticket to Ignite project (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE) to implement that.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure that the counters were at all available.